# Webdriver taking too much time to execute the script in if block using java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

While executing the code when the webelement "err" is null then webdriver  taking too much time for executing the if block but "err" is not null webdriver going to the else block and driver getting closed then ok

```
driver.findElement(By.id("UHID")).sendKeys("1234440");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();
Thread.sleep(100);
WebElement err=null;
try
{
    err=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Error']/div/p"));
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{
    System.out.println("No Such Element Exception.");
}
if(!(err != null && err.isDisplayed()))
{
    Thread.sleep(100);
    Select policytype=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("PolicyType")));
    policytype.selectByVisibleText("Corporate");                                                                
    //Select Payer
    Thread.sleep(200);
    driver.findElement(By.id("Payer")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    //Payer
    Select Payer=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Payer")));
    Payer.selectByIndex(1); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("Submit")).click();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("UHID Not Exist");
    driver.close();
}
```

please advise
thanks in advance

Comment: what is your implicit wait time set for the driver ?

Comment: i did not give any implicit wait time in my script

Comment: your question is not worded correctly according to your code.  When err is null, the else block will be executed, not the if block.  When err is not null, the if block will be executed, not the else block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
try
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    err=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Error']/div/p"));
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e)
{
    //Log your error
}
finally
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

This will tell the driver to only take 1 second to search for the "err" element before throwing an exception.  It will also reset the implicit wait, even in the event of an exception.