# time of writing in the fields is slow

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium

I am using selenium to autofill the form fields through internet explorer.But what is happening it is taking to long to fill the required fields. Is there any way by which we can increase the speed.
Here is the code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\mayank\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("http://online.newindia.co.in");
driver.findElement(By.name("loginid")).sendKeys("abc");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xyz");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
```

Comment: Please refer to a similar question answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979069/webdriver-taking-too-much-time-to-execute-the-script-in-if-block-using-java).Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually the letters are taking much time to get typed in textboxes...I need to speed up their filling

Comment: What about this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985300/selenium-webdriver-typing-very-slow-in-text-field-on-ie-browser

Comment: Can you mark the comment useful? Thanks

Comment: one more problem that i am facing is after logging the next page takes time to load and in the meanwhile error comes up as the desired element with desired id is not found. Plz suggest solution.

Comment: Use


 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='address-0']/span")));

Comment: Thanks...it worked

Answer (score -1):

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCaps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCaps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);


ieCaps.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCaps);
```

add these four lines